# Angular UI Router: ui-view positioning on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am currently developing a heavy angular-driven homepage for an agency. Now I am at the state-change. I added a page transition with a simple fade effect. Now the problem I have is, that the new `ui-view` that is being added when the state changes is prepended  before the first ui-view. Everything alright, but as the first ui-view is fading out the second is already added and the transition  looks just crappy. So, I want to have the new ui-view added after the first ui-view.

**IMPORTANT:** I am using parallax effects, so the solution with a page-container and absolute positioning isn't possible.

[image: Before ui-view change]

This image is showing what I want to have afterwards.

[image: After ui-view change]

Comment: Is `ng-animate` not enough in this case? (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate) The position the new view is inserted at is pretty much hardcoded into `ui-view`'s code: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js#L191

Comment: I am using `ng-animate`. Otherwise it would not be possible to have a transition, would it?

Comment: Ummm...yes, it would be possible to have CSS transitions applied using JavaScript without using `ng-animate`. Seeing that you _did not_ specify you are using `ng-animate` I assumed you are _not_. `ng-view` is pretty much hardcoded to insert the new view _after_ the existing one in the DOM. So your issue lies within the CSS rules for the transitions. You did not show us those either.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue, it was because I had animation on both enter and leave.

You dont need animation on both enter and leave. 
You can have animation only on leave or only on enter

E.g.

```
.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

checkout the easing in animation in this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qes7iGGvFxV2acLSxAM1?p=preview)

OR if you want animation in both enter and leave, then add a delay in animation

add delay to your transitions:

```
.ng-enter{
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease 1s;
  transition: all 2s ease 1s;
}

.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: can you create a plunker of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @HarishR's answer:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pzsDd1zPvHgdZe099upi?p=preview

We have 2 transitions:

**IN:**

```
.ng-enter {
  transition: opacity 1s ease; // autoprefixer
  opacity: 0; // start animating
}
.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1; // end animating
}
```

**OUT:**

```
.ng-exit {
  transition: opacity 1s ease; // autoprefixer
  opacity: 1; // start animating
}
.ng-exit-active {
  opacity: 0; // end animating
}
```

This will take 1 second to fade in and out the blocks. When there's only 1 block, it fades in immediately over 1 second. What if there are two blocks though (transitioning from one to another?). We can use delays and some nifty css:

```
// Selector only matches if 2 sibling animating elements exist
.ng-animate + .ng-animate {
  // Avoid pushing around DOM
  // Property disappears once the first sibling leaves
  position:absolute;
  // Delay fade-in until first sibling leaves
  transition-delay: 1s; // autoprefixer
}
```

Without this fancy selector, the first time you open a view you'd have a 1s delay before anything happens.